# How to reinit timer when it end?

Tags: javascript, date, timer

everyone! On a website I use [this timer](http://lexxus.github.io/jq-timeTo/), but I do not understand what I need to do when it end. When timer are end it should restart for next 14 days.
You may advice some books, where I can read about my problem or just aboud Date() in js.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *callback* option for this plugin that is called as soon as you timer ends:

```
$('#countdown').timeTo({
    timeTo: new Date(new Date('Sat Apr 25 2015 09:00:00 GMT+0200')),
    displayDays: 2,
    theme: "black",
    displayCaptions: true,
    fontSize: 48,
    captionSize: 14,
    // important part
    callback: function(){ 
      alert('Timer ended'); 
    }
});
```

When you want to keep track of an user's exprieing time [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)-API can be used to accomplish this.

Start expiring Timer:

Make a function to keep track of user's expiring date by using localStorage.This function returns the start date when an user visited your site the very first time. This date is used to determine whether an user has already extended the expire time of 14 days but further details are listed below:

```
function handleUserDate(expireInDays){

  var now = new Date();
  var startDate = localStorage.getItem('timerStartDate');

  // has user already visited your site?
  if(startDate){

    // is user'date expired?
    startDate = new Date(Number(startDate));
    var futureDate = new Date(startDate.getTime()+expireInDays*(1000*60*60*24));
    if(now.getTime() < futureDate.getTime()){ 
      console.log('in future');
      return startDate;
    }

  }
  console.log('in past');
  localStorage.setItem('timerStartDate', now.getTime());
  return now;

}
```

Next function is used to activate a timer and putting the number of days that are left into the *timeTo* option:

```
function startTimer(inDays){

   var now = new Date();
   var futureDate = new Date(now.getTime()+inDays*(1000*60*60*24));
   console.log(futureDate);

   $('#countdown').timeTo({
        timeTo: futureDate,
        displayDays: 2,
        theme: "black",
        displayCaptions: true,
        fontSize: 48,
        captionSize: 14,
        callback: function(){ 
          alert('Timer ended'); 
          var daysInFuture = 14;
          startTimer(daysInFuture);
        }
   });
}
```

A Function to calculate the time difference in days between start date and now:

```
function getTimeDiff(date, date2, diff){
    return Math.abs(date.getTime()-date2.getTime())/diff;
}
```

Put it all together:

```
var expireinDays = 14;// 14 day max

var startDate = handleUserDate(expireinDays);
console.log(startDate);// returns date of the very first time or when already expired it returns current date
var now = new Date();
var dayInMill = 1000*60*60*24;

var dayDifference = getTimeDiff(startDate,now,dayInMill);
dayDifference = expireinDays - dayDifference; 
console.log(dayDifference); // days left

startTimer(dayDifference); // show timer
```

Comment: when I use your code the timer does't visible, it just hide

Comment: it reinit everytime i reload the page

Comment: you did not tell that you want a whole solution but i hope this helps you :)